# « Ce n'est pas important si tu m'aimes » a-t-il deux significations ?

Tags: grammaire

1. It is not important if you love me.

   - « It » est ici une autre chose que le fait que tu m'aimes.
2. It is not important whether you love me.

   - Même si tu ne m'aimes pas, ça m'est égal.

Comment: Les deux significations sont également possibles.

Comment: Dans le second cas, je dirais plutôt *ce n'est pas important que tu m'aimes*. Mais la version avec  *si* semble possible dans ce cas aussi

Comment: Oui, à mon avis les deux sont possibles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les 2 significations sont possibles et le contexte devrait indiquer laquelle est la plus plausible. Je pense qu'on peut éviter l'ambiguïté simplement en disant :

> Ce n'est pas important si tu m'aimes **ou pas** (=> Whether)

Mais la proposition de Damien en commentaire est tout aussi valable:

> Ce n'est pas important que tu m'aimes

On pourrait aussi ajouter "ou pas" ici mais l'ambiguïté est déjà levée avec le "que"